# How to fix ddcutil for a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-20.04, monitor

Recently, I encountered a problem controlling a monitor display with a docker container. The basic idea is to connect to a display inside a docker container.

If I run the following:

```
    user@mydesktop:~$ ddcutil detect -t
```

I have the output like a following:

```
Display 1
   I2C bus:             /dev/i2c-3
   Monitor:             DEL:DELL UP3218K:JHN4J214019L

Display 2
   I2C bus:             /dev/i2c-4
   Monitor:             DEL:DELL UP3218K:JHN4J214019L
```

And I can make the connection to the display connected to my desktop with no problem.

However, when I move to a container: (this container worked before but it broke for some reason).
The output I got inside the docker container:

```
root@mydesktop:/# ddcutil detect -t
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And I can't connect to my monitor anymore.

The command I used to start the docker:

```
IMAGE=myimage
docker pull dhub:5000/$IMAGE:latest
docker run -d -it --privileged --network host \
--device /dev/i2c-0:/dev/i2c-0 \
--device /dev/i2c-1:/dev/i2c-1 \
--device /dev/i2c-2:/dev/i2c-2 \
--device /dev/i2c-3:/dev/i2c-3 \
--device /dev/i2c-4:/dev/i2c-4 \
--device /dev/i2c-5:/dev/i2c-5 \
        -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb  \
        -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
        --ipc host \
        dhub:5000/$IMAGE:latest
```

Is there any suggestion to make `ddcutil` work inside the docker container?

Comment: If you need a `--privileged` container with access to multiple host devices, it might not be appropriate to run the program inside a container.  Why do you want to introduce Docker here?

Comment: Actually, this docker image worked before. Also, using docker here is convenient to deploy an ongoing project.